# what the differences between $var and ${var}

Tags: shell

i see some code like this

```
  SERIAL_NO="121"
  if [ -z "${SERIAL_NO}" ]; then
     echo -e "ERROR: serial number of the device is not provided!"
     exit 1
  else
```

here it use ${SERIAL_NO} to got the SERIAL_NO variable.
  i want know what the difference between $var and ${var} and why use ${var} here.

thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the difference between ${var}, "$var", and "${var}" in the Bash shell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135451/what-is-the-difference-between-var-var-and-var-in-the-bash-shell)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There actually *is* a minor difference performance wise.  The reason there is a performance difference is because the braces enable the [**Parameter Expansion (PE)**](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_06_02) parser.  Without the braces the shell knows that no parameter expansion will be performed (as the braces are mandatory for PE).  The only reason to use the braces around a variable name when you *don't* want to perform a PE is to disambiguate the variable name from other text such as `var="foo"; echo ${var}name` will output `fooname`.  Without the braces the shell will try to expand the variable named `$varname` which doesn't exist.

Answer (score 1):

There is no difference, if no alphanumeric characters follow. The braces in your example are unneeded.

`"$foo42"` is the contents of `$foo42`. `"${foo}42"` is the contents of `$foo` followed by "42".

Answer (score 1):

The braces are often used to prevent shell expansion and allow back-to-back variables.  However in this case it may not be strictly needed.