# Perl %{$var} vs %$var

Tags: perl, hash, dereference

What's the difference between `%{$var}` and `%$var`? I tried this code but there's error:

> each on reference is experimental at test.pl line 21. Type of argument
>   to each on reference must be unblessed hashref or arrayref at test.pl
>   line 21.

```
use feature 'say';

%HoH = (
    1 => {
        husband   => "fred",
        pal       => "barney",
    },
    2 => {
        husband   => "george",
        wife      => "jane",
        "his boy" => "elroy",
    },
    3 => {
        husband   => "homer",
        wife      => "marge",
        kid       => "bart",
    },
);

for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    while ( ($family, $roles) = each %$HoH{$i} ) {
        say "$family: $roles";
    }
}
```

But this code works fine:

```
use feature 'say';

%HoH = (
    1 => {
        husband   => "fred",
        pal       => "barney",
    },
    2 => {
        husband   => "george",
        wife      => "jane",
        "his boy" => "elroy",
    },
    3 => {
        husband   => "homer",
        wife      => "marge",
        kid       => "bart",
    },
);

for ($i = 1; $i <= 3; $i++) {
    while ( ($family, $roles) = each %{$HoH{$i}} ) {
        say "$family: $roles";
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between ${var}, "$var", and "${var}" in the Bash shell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135451/what-is-the-difference-between-var-var-and-var-in-the-bash-shell)

Comment: @Emna: OP language is *Perl*...

Comment: Use `use strict` on your code.

Comment: @MarcoS : Ok Sorry

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `%$HoH{$i}` you make a hash reference of $HoH, while with `%{$HoH{$i}}` you make a hash reference of `$HoH{$i}`, which is what you want... And, `use strict` on your code :-)

Comment: Yes I usually use strict in my code. It's just for testing purpose. :D. Thanks for your answer. :)

Comment: @bounces, even in testing you must use it! The error when using strict in your source is quite different: `Global symbol "$HoH" requires explicit package name` and that would have given you the answer to your question.

Comment: @eballes But there's still an error `each on reference is experimental` with use strict.

Comment: @bounces: `keys on reference` is expertimental *before* perl 1.14: if you can't upgrade, you can shut up that warning with the line `no warnings 'experimental';` just before the `each`...

Comment: @MarcoS I'm using Perl 5.22. Btw did you mean before perl 5.14?

Comment: Yes, sorry, 5.14... :-(

Comment: But, if you're using 5.22, and get that warning, my comment is wrong, sorry... Did you try the "no warning experimental'" pragma, nonetheless?

Comment: Yes I tried it. The `each on reference is experimental` message disappear if I add `no warnings 'experimental';`

Answer (score 2):

Its due to the different precedence levels of resolving the hash vs subscripting the hash.  It works with the second version - `%{ $HoH{$i} }` - because you are unambiguously stating that the value returned by the lookup of `$HoH{$i}` is itself, a hashref.

Whereas `%$HoH{$i}` is interpreted as `%{ $HoH }{$i}` - ie.  the subscripting is happening after the expression `$HoH` is interpreted as a hashref - which it isn't.  `%HoH` is a hash but `$HoH` is not used - i.e. it's undefined.