# Set a file path from Jenkins' choice parameter

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, marathon, dcos

I struggled few days, But still, I could not find a solution for this.
I am trying to deploy Marathon apps with Jenkins and follow this tutorial.

https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.10/tutorials/deploy-on-marathon/

I want to configure a parameterized project for this. Eg : 
Builder can select one choice out of four choices.

[image]
As an Example: Suppose the user has selected the vault option.
Then I need to change the file name(Definition File) base on what user has selected on above options.

I am using Marathon deployment plugin.

[image]

For this configs I am getting below error :

```
18:12:40 [Marathon] Application Definition not found:
18:12:40 [Marathon] Could not find file 'deployment_files/"($CONTAINER)".json'
18:12:40 Build step 'Marathon Deployment' changed build result to FAILURE
```

Could you please help me to achieve this problem or suggest a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

When referencing a build parameter in another setting (or another parameter) the way you are trying to, I typically use the following format:

```
deployment_files/${CONTAINER}.json
```

There is some good reading to be done in the following thread on using [$VAR vs ${VAR}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135451/what-is-the-difference-between-var-var-and-var-in-the-bash-shell?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa)