# Linux shell scripting, shortening the script

Tags: linux, shell

I have the following script:

```
#!/bin/sh
cd $2
ls *.$1 | wc -l
```

I run it with: `./myct java test`

where java and test are parameters which I pass

In general, I recently started to learn shell scripting and I like to play around with it, so I was wondering if it's possible to make this script even shorter?

Thanks

Comment: These questions are better suited for [codereview.se]. And to be blunt: No. Your goal should never be to make code as short as possible, but to make it as readable as possible.

Comment: ```#!/bin/sh  ls ${2}/*.$1 | wc -l```

Comment: thank you! what is the reason for curly brackets though? cant I just write $2?

Comment: @MikeL https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135451/what-is-the-difference-between-var-var-and-var-in-the-bash-shell here you can find a good answer about brackets and quotes near variables.

Comment: The curly brackets are doing nothing useful, but all shell variables/positional parameters must be quoted `ls "$2"/*."$1"` unless you have a specific purpose in mind by leaving them unquoted and fully understand all of the implications and caveats. See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs for why you shouldn't be doing this at all though. FInally - don't name files or directories `test` as that's the name of a builtin command.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This is as short as I know how to make it:

```
#!/bin/sh
ls $2/*.$1|wc -l
```

However, I recommend you focus on reliability (checking for valid input) and maintainability (writing for clarity) instead of maximum terseness. Consider what should happen if no arguments are provided, for example; you might want to display a help message instead of an error message. This script also fails if an argument has spaces in it.

Comment: Well, I'm still thinking it could be hidden files inside of the folder, so `ls -a` instead of `ls` is better, imho.

Comment: OP did not mention this requirement. He merely wanted something similar, but shorter.

Comment: It would also fail if the file names in the target directory contained newlines or if the script arguments contained globbing characters and it would produce error messages if no files matched or .... I know the OP asked for a way to make the existing script briefer but he needs to understand that what he started with (and so any briefer version of it) is simply not a reasonable approach.

Comment: I can think of many reasons why this might fail. The question was for the shortest program (like a [quine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing))), for learning purposes, not to make a robust program. I pointed this out, then answered the question. Expanding the scope of the question is not appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Your current approach will fail when file names contain newlines (see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) and/or your args contain globbing characters (google quoting shell variables) or your directory is empty (google nullglob) or doesn't exist or... One robust way to get a count of files with a given extension in the current directory using bash would be:

```
shopt -s nullglob
arr=( "$2"/*."$1" )
echo "${#arr[@]}"
```

For example:

```
$ ls tmp
 1.java   2.java  'a'$'\n''b.java'

$ cat tst.sh
echo "Wrong:"
ls $2/*.$1|wc -l

echo "Right:"
shopt -s nullglob
arr=( "$2"/*."$1" )
echo "${#arr[@]}"

$ ./tst.sh java tmp
Wrong:
4
Right:
3
```