# How to pass argument in the custom bash function as part of a dir path?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, terminal, command

I want to define a custom bash function, which gets an argument as a part of a dir path.

I'm new to bash scripts. The codes provided online are somehow confusing for me or don't work properly.

---

For example, the expected bash script looks like:

```sh
function my_copy() {
    sudo cp ~/workspace/{$1} ~/tmp/{$2} 
}
```

If I type `my_copy a b`,

then I expect the function executes `sudo cp ~/workspace/a ~/tmp/b`
in the terminal.

---

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

If you have the below function in say `copy.sh` file and if you [source](http://www.theunixschool.com/2012/04/what-is-sourcing-file.html) it ( `source copy.sh` or `. copy.sh`) then the function call `my_copy` will work as expected.

`$1` and `$2` are [positional parameters](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Positional-Parameters.html).

i.e. when you call `my_copy a b`, `$1` will have the first command line argument as its value which is `a` in your case and `$2` which is second command line argument, will have the value `b`. The function will work as expected.

Also you have a **logical error** in the function, you have given `{$1}` instead of `${1}`. It will expand to `{a}` instead of `a` in your function and it will throw an **error** that says `cp: cannot stat '~/workspace/{a}': No such file or directory` when you run it.

Additionally, if the number of positional parameters are greater than 10, only then it is required to use `{}` in between otherwise you can avoid it. eg: `${11}` instead of `$11`.

```
   function my_copy() {
        sudo cp ~/workspace/$1 ~/tmp/$2 
    }
```

So above function will execute the statement `sudo cp ~/workspace/a ~/tmp/b` as expected.

To understand the concept, you can try `echo $1`, `echo ${1}`, `echo {$1}`, `echo {$2}`, `echo ${2}` and `echo $2` inside the script to see the resulting values.  [For more special $ sign shell variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5163144/what-are-the-special-dollar-sign-shell-variables)

Answer (score 1):

There is a syntax error in your code. You don't call a variable like `{$foo}`. If `1=a` and `2=b` then you execute

`sudo cp ~/workspace/{$1} ~/tmp/{$2}`

BASH is going to replace `$1` with `a` and `$2` with `b`, so, BASH is going to execute

`sudo cp ~/workspace/{a} ~/tmp/{b}`

That means tha `cp` is going to fail because there is no file with a name like `{a}`

There is some ways to call a variable

`echo $foo`

`echo ${foo}`

`echo "$foo"`

`echo "${foo}"`

Otherwise, your code looks good, should work.

Take a look a this links [first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18135451/what-is-the-difference-between-var-var-and-var-in-the-bash-shell) and [second](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/171346/security-implications-of-forgetting-to-quote-a-variable-in-bash-posix-shells), it's really important to quoting your variables. If you want more information about BASH or can't sleep at night try with the [Official Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/), it have everything you must know about BASH and it's a good somniferous too ;)

PS: I know $1, $2, etc are positional parameters, I called it variables because you treat it as a variable, and my anwser can be applied for both.